# A shitty question: Popo, poo, popo, pópo, popó

Tags: etymology

[This might be a better fit for the linguistics SE, but I'm especially skeptical of the German etymology, hence posting it here.]

The standard, ubiquitous and seemingly accepted etymology for German *Popo* S.m., meaning butt, ass, is given through studentensprachliches Latin *podex*, abbreviated and reduplicated to Popo. It is mainly, but not exclusively (and definitely not in the abbreviated *Po* with the same meaning), used when talking to childen, and the reduplication is considered as somehow related to children's language.

By itself, I find no reason to doubt this well-accepted derivation. However, I have now seen a multitude of very similar words with very similar meanings, in languages that are not at all similar to German, and moreover, I have come across several distinct etymologies, depending on the language.

Closest to German in this list, in English, we have *poo* and *poo-poo*, meaning not butt, but fecies, and according to [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/poop), it is supposed to be of "imitative origin".

In Italian, we have *popò*, meaning again fecies, but [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/popo) claims it was modelled after *pipí*, meaning, lo and behold, pee.

In Latin Spanish, there is *popó*, which can mean both, depending on the country you're in, and apparently absent in Peninsular Spanish. I couldn't find an etymology.

Also in French, *popo* can mean both fecies and chamberpot, and at least Wiktionary says it is derived from *pot*.

In Hungarian (!), we have *popó*, meaning butt, in concordance with the German *Popo*; I couldn't find an etymology.

Of all these etymologies, I find those I couldn't find the most convincing. I sincerely doubt that the German etymology is correct, as it appears as the most contrived in my eyes. Is there any reason to believe it (in particular believe it above e.g. claiming its being modeled after German *Pipi*), beyond appeal to authority (such as Grimm, I understand)?

Comment: Please note: there is the German word pupen/pupsen (to fart) which is maybe/most likely the equivalent to poo(p) when it comes to etymology.

Comment: Possibly related: see ISBN 978-3406629891. The author makes an excellent point about how in various languages insults/expletives are of sexual nature, whereas in German they often are about the backside and its "products".

Comment: @0xC0000022L Huh, I thought this was debunked as myth already?

Comment: @Arsak if it was, it went right past me. Care to give any pointers?

Comment: You can add Russian to the list as well.

Answer (score 3):

I can not answer everything, but I can give kind of hints that might help to approach to the right answers.

First of all: English *poo* and *poop* are pronounced with [uː] ([puː], [puːp]) while all other words have one or two [oː] as their vowel. So, I do not believe, that these words have the same origin.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poop) presents 4 different etymologies for *poop,* the most intesting is the first:

> Origin uncertain, possibly from Middle English *poupen* (“to make a gulping sound while drinking, blow on a horn, toot”). Compare Dutch *poepen* (“to defecate”), German Low German *pupen* (“to fart; break wind”).

In German the word *pupen* still exists, but more common is *pupsen,* which has derived from *pupen.* Both words mean *"to fart".* I believe, that the origin is an onomatopoetic word that imitates the sound of short farts.

I do not believe, that English *poo, poop* and German *pupen, pupsen* which all have an [uː] sound are related to German *Po, Popo* or other words with an [oː] sound.

---

Hungary belonged to the Habsburg Empire for more than 200 years (1699 - 1918) and in this time was ruled by German speaking kings, aristocrats and officials. In this time many Hungarian words were adopted in the Austria variation of German (*Palatschinken, Gulasch, Tollpatsch, Puszta*), and also many German words became part of Hungarian language (bál = Ball, fácán = Fasan, koffer = Koffer, vekker = Wecker). Maybe *popó* became part of Hungarian language this way.

Comment: Wiktionary presents one relevant etymology for the meaning in question, right? At least in English, we have a change o > u in the GVS (which is of course ignoring the ME *poupen* Wiktionary mentions, I just want to point out that this particular vowel constellation could have a fairly simple explanation). In any case, German *pupen* is a borrowing from Niederdeutsch according to Kluge, and might directly be related to the English word. But I wouldn't know how. You're probably right in separating poo from Popo though, no pun intended (all right, maybe a little bit).

Comment: As for Hungarian: Tollpatsch!? Wow, who knew! But then, I have trouble believing that one would need a loanword for conveying the meaning of butt. Koffer, Wecker, Ball (Tanzball!), Fasan, fine, Hungarians had no old words for those things that were probably relevant mostly in a Nobility context, and if they had, using the language of the Habsburgians is a matter of social distinction. But doing so for a child's tushy? I don't know. It's possible I guess. Still, all of this leaves me wondering all the more about *Podex.*

Comment: About Tollpatsch: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollpatsch), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Tollpatsch), [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tollpatsch), [wissen.de](https://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/tollpatsch)

Comment: "Maybe popó became part of Hungarian language this way." orvmaybe vice-versa?

Comment: It should be noted that *p* was regularly turned *f* through Grimm's law in Germanic. So it seems exceedingly unlikely that *popo* were not a loan word. This makes it so interesting. I know a variant *Popöter* and I suppose *Pöter(le)* also exists. Even if akin to *podex*, the different ending would likely imply an older date, but how old I really can't say. The accentuation also seems foreign. Armes Putput.

Comment: @vectory: You are right. The vast majority of words used in German that start with *»Po-«* or *»po-«* are loanwords: *Politik, Polizei, Position, Post, positiv, Polen, Potenzial, Pokal, populär, ...* Only *pochen* and *poltern* seems to have roots in old high german. But both verbs derive from words that imitate a sound. This means for *Popo,* that it is very likely, that it either is a loanword from another language, or has an onomatopoetic root. But this still can mean, that Hungarian *popó* was imported from Austria.